# Can I write this? - "Although [reason 1], although [reason 2], and although [reason 3], this thing didn't happen."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Let's say that I want to express that although all the conditions were there for something to happen, it didn't happen.

Is it correct, in order to emphasize the contradiction, to write a repetition of **although** like this:

> Although [reason 1], although [reason 2], and although [reason 3], *this thing didn't happen.*

Thank you.

Comment: You're enumerating the reasons here; the second and third although is not necessary. If this thing should have happened with a very high probability given the three reasons, you can emphasize it with a carefully placed `even` between `and` and [reason 3], so it becomes `Although [reason 1], [reason2] and even [reason 3], this thing didn't happen` (the verb _happen_ remains in present tense form as _didn't_ already tells you the sentence is in past tense). You can also use `despite` in place of `although` in such contexts.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it breaks any actual grammatical rules, but an English speaker would never say this. Only the first 'although' is needed:

> Although the roads were clear, the weather was good, and he set off an hour early, John was still late for work.

If there are two sets of reasons caused by different things, you could break up the second group with 'and though':

> Although John's car was clean, well kept, and fast; and though the roads were clear, clean, and wide, John was *still* late for work.

The first group of conditions are why his car should be able to get him there, and the second set of conditions are why the roads shouldn't have slowed him down.

Comment: I'm not sure an English speaker would never say it. Maybe not when having an informal conversation, but it has been used more formally. ["We shall fight in France, we shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and growing strength in the air, we shall defend our island, whatever the cost may be."](http://www.winstonchurchill.org/learn/speeches/speeches-of-winston-churchill/128-we-shall-fight-on-the-beaches "Winston Churchill speech") isn't as powerful if you say "We shall fight in France, on the seas and oceans, and in the air to defend our island."

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.  The name for this rhetorical device is "anaphora".

Comment: A little more elaboration on why and when you would use anaphora might be helpful. One of the more famous usages from _A Tale of Two Cities_ by Charles Dickens might help illustrate. "**It was** the best of times, **it was** the worst of times, **it was** the age of wisdom, **it was** the age of foolishness, **it was** the epoch of belief, **it was** the epoch of incredulity, **it was** the season of Light, **it was** the season of Darkness, **it was** the spring of hope, **it was** the winter of despair, ..."